# Before block in rspec is running before every test when it should run only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am running a `before do` at the beginning of my tests. I would like this `before to` be executed once before running my tests. However at the moment it is running before each test :

```
context "worker has failed first time and has generated only part of licenses" do
      before do
        order.already_went_through_license_worker = true
        order.save!
        order.pre_calculate_licenses
        partial_generate_from_bundles(order.expected_license_bundles)
        LicenseService.new.create_from_order(order.id)
      end
      let!(:licenses){ License.where(order_id: order.id)}
      specify { subject.count.should == 34 }
      specify { subject.pluck(:is_from_offer_special).count(true).should == 4}
      specify { subject.pluck(:is_from_offer_special).count(false).should == 30 }
      specify { subject.pluck("license_offer.offer_original_id").compact.map(&:values).flatten.count(offer.id).should == 30}
      specify { subject.pluck("license_offer_special.offer_special_original_id").compact.map(&:values).flatten.count(offer_special_cyclic.id).should == 3}
      specify { subject.pluck("license_offer_special.offer_special_original_id").compact.map(&:values).flatten.count(offer_special_non_cyclic.id).should == 1 }
    end
```

When I change it to before(:all) I get an error :

```
 let declaration `order` accessed in a `before(:context)` hook at:
```

How can I make the before block run only once.

Comment: What is `order` as I do not see a declaration for `order`. I have a feeling this is `let(:order) { Order.new(#...) }` and this is your actual error when using `before(:all)` because it creates a contextual shift between a memoized helper `let` and a contextual setup `before(:all)`

Comment: you left out `subject` declaration - can you paste it as well?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make the before block run only once.

`before(:all)`, you already did that.

> When I change it to `before(:all)` I get an error:

That's a different, completely unrelated error. Your block **does** run only once, which is what you asked. The problem here is that a context-level block is trying to access example-level declarations. Kinda like trying to access instance variables from class methods: those variables don't exist yet!

One possible approach is to inline all dependencies (don't use `let`, put code directly into the block):

```
before :all do
  order = create :order # or whatever
  order.already_went_through_license_worker = true
  order.save!
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **one** `specify` block approach if nothing else helps:

```
specify do 
 subject.count.should == 34
 subject.pluck(:is_from_offer_special).count(true).should == 4
 #...
end
```

But this has one drawback: if one expectation fails, the ones after it will not run. But you can fix that if you [aggregate failures](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-7/docs/aggregating-failures)

```
specify aggregate_failures: true do 
 subject.count.should == 34
 subject.pluck(:is_from_offer_special).count(true).should == 4
 #...
end
```

Comment: Ah, indeed. While not exactly what is being asked, this is, IMHO, a superior solution. With aggregate_failures, there's really not much sense in having one-liner tests with expensive setup. I myself use it all the time.

Comment: At some point you also realize that all this setup time adds up, so you want to combine all this expectations for one setup to trim some of the specs time - this is useful then as well.